# How to rotate an object to continually touch the uneven surface of another rotating object?

Tags: constraints, drivers

How to rotate an object to continually touch the uneven surface of another rotating object?

- Object A (black) rotates using a variable speed driver to another
  object's rotation. Object A has an uneven circumference against which
  Object B needs to lean.
- Object B (gold) needs to pivot back and forth as it's little roller
  rolls along object A's uneven circumference as A continually rotates.
- It needs to be a simulation, not keyframed animation so object B will
  always follow A regardless of A's rotational speed forward or
  backward.

Once this contraption is built, It will be mounted on a robot arm moving everywhere in world space and orientation.

I've tried adding a complicated driver to Object B based on the radian rotation sections of Object B.[image]

I've tried hard body simulation, but it just gets hung up and i cannot figure out how to get Object B to continually lean against the circumference of Object A. I've even tried adding an invisible spring and I couldn't get it to work.

https://imgur.com/cJ6Z1Jb

Comment: Have you tried a Rigid Body motor and hinge combination? https://youtu.be/gVrvzBjZwgk

Comment: Would you describe this a s a cam? (That might be more searchable)

Comment: This is really something better done with a rigid body sim than with constraints and drivers; you can still animate the wheel as desired.  Here's my basic test setup: https://pasteboard.co/rVwk2skYInr5.png which shows you object origins and RB constraint settings. Note that you need to use mesh collision for any concave objects.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple Geometry Nodes setup:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Collision Detection by Rotating with Python

I just wanted to post a scripting option for those who are more comfortable with Python than the physics engine. This may not be the solution with the best performance.

[image]

#### The Script

```py
"""This script adds a frame-change handler to rotate ObjectA
until it contacts ObjectB.
"""

import bpy
import math
from mathutils import Vector
import bmesh
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree


def create_bvh(obj):
    """Create a bvh tree for the given object."""
    
    bm = bmesh.new()
    depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    evaluated_obj = obj.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
    mesh = evaluated_obj.to_mesh()
    bm.from_mesh(mesh)
    
    bm.transform(obj.matrix_world)
    bvh = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm)
    
    evaluated_obj.to_mesh_clear()
    bm.free()
    
    return bvh


def collision(obj1, obj2):
    """Return True if there is a collision between obj1 and obj2."""
    
    # Create BVH trees for each object
    bvh1 = create_bvh(obj1)
    bvh2 = create_bvh(obj2)

    # Check for overlaps between the two BVH trees
    overlapping_pairs = bvh1.overlap(bvh2)
    
    if overlapping_pairs:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    

def rotate_to_contact(scene):
    """Rotate ObjectA until it contacts ObjectB"""
    
    object_a = bpy.data.objects["ObjectA"]
    object_b = bpy.data.objects["ObjectB"]

    # Reset the rotation just beyond the widest part of the
    # rotating object in order to minimize the number of steps required.
    object_a.rotation_euler.z = -1.14
    
    # Set the tiny step by which to rotate
    # Decrease this for higher accuracy but slower playback
    angle_increment = math.radians(-.5)

    for _ in range(2000):
        
        # Make a tiny rotation and check for a collision.
        object_a.rotation_euler.rotate_axis("Z", angle_increment)
        bpy.context.view_layer.update()
        if collision(object_a, object_b):
            break
    
    # Update the scene for good measure
    bpy.context.view_layer.update() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(rotate_to_contact)
```